# Binding MediaElement to slider position in WPF

Tags: wpf, slider, mediaelement

Tried binding Maximum value of slider to media element's duration and binding slider's current value to the position of media element, but but for some reasons it doesn't.

I want the slider to move it's thumb while the video is playing.

```
<Slider x:Name="videoSlider" Value="{Binding ElementName=mp3MediaElement, Path=Position}" 
ValueChanged="videoSlider_ValueChanged" IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" 
Maximum="{Binding ElementName=mp3MediaElement, Path=NaturalDuration}" 
AllowDrop="True" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=mp3MediaElement}" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I didn't use binding..
I had a similar issue and used timer for this (My code is in Silverlight by it suppose to be the same on WPF):

First direction (movie updates the slider)

```
private TimeSpan TotalTime;

private void MyMediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TotalTime = MyMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;

            // Create a timer that will update the counters and the time slider
            timerVideoTime = new DispatcherTimer();
            timerVideoTime.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            timerVideoTime.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timerVideoTime.Start();
        }

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Check if the movie finished calculate it's total time
            if (MyMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds > 0)
            {
                if (TotalTime.TotalSeconds > 0)
                {
                    // Updating time slider
                    timeSlider.Value = MyMediaElement.Position.TotalSeconds /
                                       TotalTime.TotalSeconds;
                }
            }
        }
```

Second direction (user updates the slider)
on form ctor or something like this write the following line:

```
timeSlider.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, 
                      new MouseButtonEventHandler(timeSlider_MouseLeftButtonUp), 
                      true);
```

and the event handler is:

```
private void timeSlider_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (TotalTime.TotalSeconds > 0)
            {
                MyMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeSlider.Value * TotalTime.TotalSeconds);
            }
        }
```

Comment: well it keeps calling ValueChanged event, which I use when the user clicks on the slider, so it moves to that location of media file. slider value is changing but it doesn't reflect on the UI :(

Comment: it started working since I removed the other logic: when user clicks the slider, it jumps to that location. Can you tell me how you solved that?

Comment: it calls the handler, but keeps a value for a less than second ( i see it move to the clicked point), and then it returns to the current playing position. The sound is playing continuously all the time.

Comment: I forgot to add line `timeSlider.AddHandler` but now it restarts the media file (playing from the begining on every click).

Comment: I've solved it. I had been messed with milliseconds instead of seconds, and now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Both Slider properties Value and Maximum are of type Double. You are trying to bind to values of types `TimeSpan` and `Duration` correspondingly and thats why the binding system doesn't work in your case.

You may try to write a convertor, or to bind to `NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` property.

Hope this helps.

By the way if some of your bindings do not work you may check binding errors in Visual Studio "Output" window.

Comment: I used proper format. I still don't understand converters enough, since I'm a beginner. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the slider was not updating UI of the MediaElement..
I spent quite some time trying to fix it and I am not sure it will help others.
But Just in case someone else hit that problem, do note that there is a **ScrubbingEnabled** property in media element which allows the UI of the MediaElement to automatically seek the correct picture according to the position. 
Very useful when you are in a pause-mode and trying to drag the slider.
Just add: `ScrubbingEnabled="True"` in the XAML of your MediaElement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up using for my UWP app.

This answer just addresses the specific question; moving the slider thumb in response to playback. It doesn't handle changing the video position in response to the user moving the slider.

First add these:

```
private DispatcherTimer timerVideoPlayback;

private void TimerVideoPlayback_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    long currentMediaTicks = mediaElement.Position.Ticks;
    long totalMediaTicks = mediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.Ticks;

    if (totalMediaTicks > 0)
        slider.Value = (double)currentMediaTicks / totalMediaTicks * 100;
    else
        slider.Value = 0;
}
```

Then when your video starts, start the timer:

```
timerVideoPlayback = new DispatcherTimer();
timerVideoPlayback.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
timerVideoPlayback.Tick += TimerVideoPlayback_Tick;
timerVideoPlayback.Start();
```

I used a 10 ms interval to keep the slider motion steady. Use any value you like.

And don't forget to stop that timer when playback ends:

```
timerVideoPlayback.Stop();
```

Comment: Fwiw, the built in UWP media element updates it's slider every 200 - 250 ms, for performance reasons. 10 ms is fast (technically it's about 16ms for a screen refresh, although you can't trust for that accurate ticking on a DispatcherTimer), but it's a lot more costly that it needs to be - especially using a DispatcherTimer and firing a Layout update on the slider constantly. Most media players don't update that fast for perf / efficiency reasons.