# Binding MediaElment's position to a Slider

Tags: wpf

I want to Binding MediaElment's Position to a Slider.But I know `Position` is not a DependencyProperty.I have searched some answers([Binding MediaElement to slider position in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208959/binding-mediaelement-to-slider-position-in-wpf)) It use DispatcherTimer. Is there another answer？ If I want to use Binding. How can I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look this,msdn has provide a solution.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748248.aspx